# Drag and drop item in listview

Tags: listview

I have a listview, buttons, textview, edittext, imageview which are covered by a scrollview.

Now, I want to drag and drop the item in the listview to sort the list. However, I got the problem when drag because scrollview maybe takes control the touch listener when I drag item in the listview.

There are many people said that I shouldn't use listview in a scrollview but this is the requirement.

Thus, how can I do? I meant how can I lock the touch of the scroll view while I drag item in the listview. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to lock the scroll of the scrollview while draging the item in the listview. 
That's everything I can get till now. If you have any better solutions, tell me please, thanks

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  
lv.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```